# Inverting the Y Axis

Tags: openlayers

I'm new to OpenLayers and trying to figure out the best approach to inverting the Y axis so the Y origin is at the top of the extent instead of the bottom (plotting `[0, 0]` would be at the top left instead of the bottom left). I figured that I could update the extent to be something like `[0, {-1 * map height}, {map width}, 0]`, but now I need to apply a transformation to the Y coordinates of all coordinate data going into the map to be the inverse (having coordinate `[50, 100]` transformed to `[50, -100]`.

I'm trying to find a way that applies this transformation *inside* of OL instead of mutating the data going into it because I'd like to keep track of transformations within the OL code itself. So I was checking out the `transform` method on features, but wasn't able to hook into any transformative function in OL.

So my questions are, 1) Is this this best approach to inverse the Y axis in OpenLayers; and 2) if it is, how can I hook into OL to apply a transformation on all coordinates of a feature?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a simple transform between data projection and view projection

```
addCoordinateTransforms(
  dataProjection,
  viewProjection,
  function (coordinate) {
    return [coordinate[0], -coordinate[1]];
  },
  function (coordinate) {
    return [coordinate[0], -coordinate[1]];
  }
);
```

This https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-mendeleev-w8cf8?file=/main.js flips an image layer, but the projections should work equally well as the dataProjection and featureProjection in a vector source.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I was looking at `addCoordinateTransforms` but wasn't able to successfully get it to apply transformations on feature coordinates in a vector layer.

I put an example of what I'm trying to do at https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-cherry-vv3nd?file=/main.js, where `[0, 0]` would be in the upper-left of the map and `[1024, 968]` would be in the lower right. In order to register the transformations in  `addCoordinateTransforms` to apply, do I have to supply a different type of layer other than a vector layer?

Thanks again!

Comment: If you are creating features directly you would need `geometry: new Point([1024, 968]).transform(dataProjection, viewProjection)`
 If you were calling the readFeature method of a format you would need `{dataProjection: dataProjection, featureProjection: viewProjection}`as the options

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help Mike!